# Find some sequence of (probability) measures $\mathbb{P}_i$ such that $\mathbb{P}_i ≪ \mathbb{P}$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\{\mathbb{P}_i\}$, for $ i\in \mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of probability measures on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, then find a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ where each sequence $\mathbb{P}_i$ is absolutely continuous to $\mathbb{P}$.

I know that probability measure $\mathbb{P_i}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to another probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ if $\mathbb{P}(A)=0$ implies $\mathbb{P}_i(A)=0$ for any subset $\mathcal{F}$ of $\Omega$. I am a little stuck on what a sequence of probability measures will look like and where to begin with this! Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\mathbb P(E)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {\mathbb P_k (E)} {2^{k}}$. To show that this is countably additive you can use Tonelli's Theorem. $\mathbb P$ is a probability measure and each $\mathbb P$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mathbb P$.

Comment: Thanks - just out of interest if you know if there is a more direct way of showing it is a measure without Tonelli's Theorem? Trying to show the following $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {\mathbb P_k (\cup_{k=1}^n E_i)} {2^{k}} = \sum_{i=1}^n  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {\mathbb P_k (E_i)} {2^{k}}$

Comment: @Btzzzz If $a_{ij} \geq 0$ for all $i,j$ then $\sum_i \sum_j a_{ij}=\sum_j \sum_i a_{ij}$. This can be proved easily without Tonelli's Theorem. Just note that the sum of a positive series is (not only the limit but also) the supremum of the partial sums. Since $sup_m\sup_n=\sup_n\sup_m$ always we get equality of the two sums.